# Python Datetime: All Items From Yesterday

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

In Python, if I wanted to do a check for all items from yesterday would I do something like:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

if datetime.datetime.today() - timedelta(days=2) < item_to_check < datetime.datetime.today():
```

Would this pull all items from yesterday and is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd try something easier ;-)

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
if item_to_check.date() == yesterday:
    # yup!
```

Note that your:

```
item_to_check < datetime.datetime.today()
```

is true for any item that occurred before the second you called `datetime.datetime.today()`.  My `date.today()` doesn't include hours, minutes or seconds (i.e., it has no "time" component).

Comment: Yup, and if you have lots of items then you can do this in a list using list comprehension. yesterday_items = [item for item in items if item.date() == yesterday]

Comment: lol.  I think we were typing the same thing.  you beat me to it by about 10 seconds.  :)

Comment: @MattJohnson, duplicate answers are common here.  Include a lot more explanation than mine, and yours will probably be accepted ;-)

Comment: That's ok.  You can have this one. I'll get the next. :)