# Python to download file from FTP Server if file has been added into FTP server in last N hour ago?

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

Can you please help with download file from FTP server if file has been added into last 12 hours ago, currently I'm able to download latest file from FTP server, but not sure how to add logic for last 12 hours ago if files has been added into ftp server

```
import csv
from ftplib import FTP
import os
import time,glob
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

list_of_file =glob.glob(".\*csv*")
latest_file = max(list_of_file, key=os.path.getatime,default=None)
filename = os.path.basename('latest_file')
ftp = FTP(host='hostname')
ftp.login(user='username',passwd='pass')
ftp.cwd("Inbox")
names = ftp.nlst()

finale_names = [line for line in names if 'restaurant file' in line]

latest_time = None
latest_name = None
for name in finale_names:
        time_1 = ftp.sendcmd("MDTM " + name)
        if (latest_time is None) or (time_1 > latest_time):
                latest_name = name
                latest_time = time_1
print(latest_name)

if latest_name==filename:
        print("No new file available in the FTP server")
else:
        
        print(latest_name," is available for downloading...")
        with open("C:\Files\restaurant \\" + latest_name, 'wb') as f:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ latest_name, f.write)
        print("filehasbeendownload")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the time threshold. Parse the times returned by `MDTM`. And compare:

```
n = 4
limit = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=n)

for name in finale_names:
    resp = ftp.sendcmd("MDTM " + name)
    # extract "yyyymmddhhmmss" part of the 213 response
    timestr = resp[4:18]
    time = datetime.strptime(timestr, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    if time > limit:
        # Download
```

---

Though if your server supports `MLSD` command, you better use that, instead of inefficiently calling `MDTM` for each and every file:
[Download only yesterday's file with FTP in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63574209/850848)

Or you can use `LIST`. For understanding ways of retrieving file timestamps, see:
[How to get FTP file's modify time using Python ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29026709/850848)

Comment: Thanks but I tried, its falls with the print statement not available, and a file is available 
n = 6
limit = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=n)

for name in finale_names:
    resp = ftp.sendcmd("MDTM " + name)
    timestr = resp[4:18]
    time = datetime.strptime(timestr, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    if time > limit:
        print(latest_name," is available for downloading...")
        with open("C:\Files\folder\\" + latest_name, 'wb') as f:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ latest_name, f.write)
            
    else:
         print ("Not available")

Comment: There's no `latest_name` anymore, right? There's `name`. + The `else: print ("Not available")` makes no sense either.

Comment: Else for if file wouldn't download, and  I removed latest name
` finale_names = [line for line in names if 'Portfolio_History_CapIQ' in line]
n = 6
limit = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=n)
for name in finale_names:
    resp = ftp.sendcmd("MDTM " + name)
    timestr = resp[4:18]
    time = datetime.strptime(timestr, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    print(time)
    if time > limit:
        print(name," is available for downloading...")
        with open("C:\Files\Penderfund\\" + name, 'wb') as f:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ name, f.write)
    else:
         print ("Not available") `

Comment: I do not understand you comment. Do you still have any problems? Or does it work now?

Comment: Still its pending, sorry for the code

Comment: Yes its working now, but can you just tell me what is use of this line -  timestr = resp[4:18]

Thanks for this

Comment: The response (`resp`) to `MDTM` command from the server is like `213 20220906142234.753`. The `resp[4:18]` extracts `20220906142234`.